# How does revert work?

Tags: solidity, remix

I am wondering how the revert keyword works here in this program.
In my interpretation  for the function "register", the if statement asks if lookup[name] is equal to an address of 0 (which is a contract address?). Then, if the address is NOT equal to a contract address, revert (which is similar to require?) the error. The program works fine but I know that I'm not understanding revert correctly here.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: AGPL-3.0-only
pragma solidity ^0.8.10;

contract LilENS {
    /// ERRORS ///

    /// @notice Thrown when trying to update a name you don't own
    error Unauthorized();

    /// @notice Thrown when trying to register a name that's already taken
    error AlreadyRegistered();

    /// @notice Stores the registered names and their addresses
    /// @dev This automatically generates a getter for us!
    mapping(string => address) public lookup;

    /// @notice Registers a new name, and points it to your address
    /// @param name The name to register
    function register(string memory name) public payable {
        if (lookup[name] != address(0)) revert AlreadyRegistered();

        lookup[name] = msg.sender;
    }

    /// @notice Allows the owner of a name to point it to a different address
    /// @param name The name to update
    /// @param addr The new address this name should point to
    function update(string memory name, address addr) public payable {
        if (msg.sender != lookup[name]) revert Unauthorized();

        lookup[name] = addr;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

take a look at the [doc of mappings](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.4.21/types.html#mappings)

> Mappings can be seen as hash tables which are virtually initialized such that every possible key exists and is mapped to a value whose byte-representation is all zeros: a type’s default value.

so the following line:

```
 if (lookup[name] != address(0)) revert AlreadyRegistered();
```

is checking if for the specific key (parameter name) the value of the mapping is different than the **default value** which is, as you can see in the doc: byte-representation of all zeros (that is what **address(0)** return)

If the value for that key is address(0) mean that the key was not registered yet

So in order to answer your question:

> How does revert work?

the above mentioned line is telling if the name was already registered revert with the custom error AlreadyRegisted